# I'm not able to get the correct selected item position of a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

```
TextView tvRes;
Button btn;
String fgpa;
int maxGrade[]=new int[] {4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2};
double rcvdGrade[]=new double[9];
double[] fres=new double[9];
int ssp1;
double sumRes=0,sumPoints=0;
double fail=0;
Spinner sp1,sp2,sp3,sp4,sp5,sp6,sp7,sp8,sp9;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp1 = findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    sp2 = findViewById(R.id.sp2);
    sp3 = findViewById(R.id.sp3);
    sp4 = findViewById(R.id.sp4);
    sp5 = findViewById(R.id.sp5);
    sp6 = findViewById(R.id.sp6);
    sp7 = findViewById(R.id.sp7);
    sp8 = findViewById(R.id.sp8);
    sp9 = findViewById(R.id.sp9);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
    tvRes=findViewById(R.id.tvRes);
    adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.grades,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp4.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp5.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp6.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp7.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp8.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp9.setAdapter(adapter);
    ssp1=sp1.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if(ssp1==0){
            rcvdGrade[0]=10;
        }
        if (ssp1=='1'){
            rcvdGrade[0]=9;
        }
         if(ssp1=='2'){
            rcvdGrade[0]=8;
        }
        if(ssp1=='3'){
            rcvdGrade[0]=7;
        }
        if(ssp1=='4'){
            rcvdGrade[0]=6;
        }
         if(ssp1=='5'){
        rcvdGrade[0]=5;
        }
        if(ssp1=='6'){
            fail=0;
        }
```

I am new to programming. I am trying to get a `Spinner` position and by using that value, I will assign a value to a variable from which I can calculate a percentage. **But this code always selects the first condition and sets the value to 10**. I cannot figure out what's wrong with this code. Help me, guys. Also, if you have any suggestions or improvements with this code, please let me know, friends. Thanks in advance.

**Extra:** I also tried using the `getSelectedItemPosition();` function directly on the `if` statement and also tried to get the values by comparing the text in the `Spinner` but it gives me the same (always selects the first condition) result.

Comment: If I could make a suggestion, I would make an array of the values that represent the position of the spinner. For example, if you had the array `int[] sp1Array = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6};`, `getSelectedItemPosition()` would return the index in `sp1Array` that you want: `rcvdGrade[0] = sp1Array[sp1.getSelectedItemPosition()];`

Comment: In your code, `ssp1` is an `int` but in your `if` statements, you are comparing it to `char`s. I don't know if that is what you intend or not.

Comment: I also tried the code without that ' ' symbols, but it give me the exact wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running as soon as the activity is created. That means it gets the position of the spinner as soon as it's made, which will always be position zero. That code will not run again to give you a different value. You need to set up an `OnItemSelectedListener` so the value will change every time you change the position of the spinner.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Called anytime a spinner dropdown item is clicked
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    };
```

Then in your `onCreate()` method write this:

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
```

This is only applying to sp1, but if you set all the spinners with this same listener, know that the parameter `parent` in the listener is the spinner that changed. If you need to know which spinner changed, use the `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods.

In `onCreate()`:

```
sp1.setTag("sp1");
sp2.setTag("sp2");
// set Listeners, etc
```

In your `onItemSelected()`

```
if (parent.getTag().equals("sp1")) //It was sp1 that changed
       // do stuff
    else if (parent.getTag().equals("sp2")) //sp2 changed
       // do other stuff
```

EDIT: As per your request, here is a combination of the above:

```
// Previous declarations
int ssp1;
double sumRes=0,sumPoints=0;
double fail=0;
Spinner sp1,sp2,sp3,sp4,sp5,sp6,sp7,sp8,sp9;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener =
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int position = parent.getSelectedItemPosition(); // also equal to the parameter position
            if (parent.getTag().equals("sp1")) // sp1 was changed this time
                // Change rcvdGrade[0] as you please
            else if (parent.getTag().equals("sp2")) // sp2 changed
                // Change rcvdGrade[1] as you please
            else if (parent.getTag().equals("sp3")) //etc
                //etc
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // This is required to make the listener happy, but leave it blank
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp1 = findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    sp2 = findViewById(R.id.sp2);
    sp3 = findViewById(R.id.sp3);
    // others set, adapters set, etc
    sp1.setTag("sp1");
    sp2.setTag("sp2");
    sp3.setTag("sp3");
    // etc
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
    // etc
}
```

I'm not here to write all your code, but I hope this helps you understand this better. If not, please look up tutorials for the `OnItemSelectedListener` because that is what you want to best work with spinners. If you are certain you want to use `OnClickListener`, then set that to a button instead.

Comment: Really sorry sir, I cannot able to understand your answer. If you have time, please reply me with the code sir  [ Please sir]. In the meantime, I am working on learning set item click listener. Really thank you, sir, for your answer.

Comment: The above code in the big block (starting with `private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()`) is declared in the class along with your other declarations, like `double fail = 0;` and `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;`. If any number of spinners set this as their `OnItemSelectedListener`, they will run that piece of code every time you click one of their dropdown items, also sending their own information to use as the parameters `parent`, `view`, `position` and `id`; Click Listeners are best used for buttons only, not for spinners.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help bro. You made my day. Cheers!